# Django NoReverseMatch exception

Tags: django

I have got a function refresh in my views.py file and I want to redirect it to another function jenkinsreport in the same file but I am getting NoReverseMatch error.Can someone please point what am I doing wrong.I am new to Django so any help would be appreciated.I have looked for solution but I cant seem to fix it.

```
#views.py

def refresh(request):
        server = jenkins.Jenkins('link',username=username,password='password')
        jobs = server.get_jobs()
        job_name_list=[]
        build_number_list=[]
        build_info_list=[]
        status_list_dict={}
        tme=time.time()
        print tme
        time_now=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(tme))
        print time_now
        tmelastmonth=tme-2592000
        time_from=time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(tmelastmonth))
        tmemiliseconds=tmelastmonth*1000
        #print dir(server)
        for i in range(len(jobs)):
                job_name=jobs[i]['name']
                job_name_list.append(job_name)
        for i in range(len(job_name_list)):
                job_info=server.get_job_info(job_name_list[i])
                lastbuilt=job_info['lastSuccessfulBuild']
                if lastbuilt:
                        b_number=job_info['lastSuccessfulBuild']['number']
                        build_number_list.append(b_number)
                build_zipped=zip(job_name_list,build_number_list)
        print build_zipped
        for i ,j in build_zipped:
                success=0
                failure=0
                unstable=0
                aborted=0
                try:
                        for k in range(j,1,-1):
                                build_info=server.get_build_info(i,k)
                                if build_info['timestamp']<tmemiliseconds:
                                        break
                                build_info_list.append(build_info)
                                status=build_info['result']
                                if status=="SUCCESS":
                                        success+=1
                                elif status=="FAILURE":
                                        failure+=1
                                elif status=="UNSTABLE":
                                        unstable+=1
                                else:
                                        aborted+=1
                                statuscount=[success,failure,unstable,aborted]
                                status_list_dict[i]=statuscount

                except:
                        pass

        for job in status_list_dict:
                build_status_object = Build_status_count.objects.filter(Job_name=job)
                if not build_status_object:
                        build_status_count = Build_status_count()
                        build_status_count.Job_name =job
                        build_status_count.Time_from = time_from
                        build_status_count.Time_to= time_now
                        build_status_count.Successful=status_list_dict[job][0]
                        build_status_count.Failure=status_list_dict[job][1]
                        build_status_count.Unstable=status_list_dict[job][2]
                        build_status_count.Aborted=status_list_dict[job][3]
                        build_status_count.save()
                else:
                        for obj in build_status_object:
                                obj.Time_from = time_from
                                obj.Time_to=time_now
                                obj.Successful=status_list_dict[job][0]
                                obj.Failure=status_list_dict[job][1]
                                obj.Unstable=status_list_dict[job][2]
                                obj.Aborted=status_list_dict[job][3]

                                obj.save()
        return redirect('jenkinsreport')

def jenkinsreport(request):
        Build=Build_status_count.objects.all()
        status_list_dict={}
        testdict={}
        for build in Build:
                job_name=build.Job_name
                jb=job_name.encode("utf-8")
                success=build.Successful
                sc=success.encode("utf-8")
                scint=int(sc)
                failure=build.Failure
                Unstable=build.Unstable
                Aborted=build.Aborted
                status_list=[int(success),int(failure),int(Unstable),int(Aborted)]
                status_list_dict[jb]=scint
                testdict[jb]=status_list


        return render(request,'jenkinsapp/index.html',{'status_count_list': json.dumps(status_list_dict),'testdict': json.dumps(testdict)})
```

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns =[

        url(r'^jenkinsreport/$',views.jenkinsreport,name='jenkinreport'),
        url(r'^refresh/$',views.refresh,name='refresh')

        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a typing error in name of urls.py.It should have been jenkinsreport instead of jenkinreport.Sorry guys for your time